# can't obtain the correct hour with moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

ok I recieve a hour

```
"2017-09-12T18:30:00-04:00"
```

but when I want put the hour un format 24hours:

```
 moment(data[i].hora_llegada, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("HH:mm:ss"),¿
```

I obtain OUTPUT:

```
"06:30:00"
```

this is 6:30 am but I need the 18:30

this happen when I insert the next array:

```
dataAssistsUser.push({
  actualizacion_registro: data[i].actualizacion_registro,
  baja: data[i].baja,
  falta: data[i].falta,
  fecha_laboral: moment(data[i].fecha_laboral, ['YYYY-MM-DD']).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  fecha_registro: data[i].fecha_registro, 
  hora_llegada: moment(data[i].hora_llegada, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm:ss"), //problem here
  hora_salida: moment(data[i].hora_salida, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm:ss"), //problem here
  id: data[i].id,
  total_atraso: moment(data[i].total_atraso, ['YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss']).format('mm:ss'),
  user: data[i].user,
  user_id: data[i].user_id,
  vacacion: data[i].vacacion
});
```

Comment: Your format string `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` does not match your date string `"2017-09-12T18:30:00-04:00"`

Comment: Also, this only ever shows `18:30:00` for me, even with the bad format string

Comment: Also, if the **actual problem** is with `format("h:mm:ss")` as you indicate with that code comment, then are you really surprised that "h" shows the hour in 12-hour format? RTFM ~ https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
moment(data[i].hora_llegada, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("HH:mm:ss")
```

into:

```
moment(data[i].hora_llegada, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss").format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Whilst this is a potential problem, it's not the one causing OP's time to be formatted the way it is

Comment: @Phil, Actually his format string is in 12 hour format here `hora_llegada: moment(data[i].hora_llegada, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm:ss"), //problem here`. So I believe it is the one causing this problem.